CSS backdrop-filter: blur() for anchor tag is not working in chrome browser
The anchor tag is shown as a button with a transparent background and white borders. I am using the .class for styling. The backdrop property works in the Firefox browser but not in Chrome, I've also used "-webkit-backdrop-filter" but it shows an invalid property value in Chrome.
Chrome-browser-preview

Firefox-browser-preview
Please let me know if someone can help me out of this.

provide your code.

Nested backdrop-filters do not render in Chrome. However you can workaround this limitation by putting your backdrop-filter on a :before pseudo element instead.
backdrop-filter not working for nested elements in Chrome provides an in depth look at why this is the case for Chrome.

When writing an answer like this, you may want to consider flagging the question as a duplicate instead, since the question wording seems pretty similar and it looks like the answer doesn't need any extra question-specific clarifications (which means the question is essentially identical).
